# Open collapse from parent Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a ***`<b-collapse>`*** in a child and I try to open/close it from my parent.
For models I have $bvModal, but for collapse I didn't find something similar.

**Parent**

```
<b-button @isVisible="visible=true">View more</b-button>
<collapse id="collapse-1"></collapse>
```

**Child**

```
 <b-collapse  @click="$emit('isVisible')" class="mt-2" v-bind="$attrs">
 ....code...
 </b-collapse>

data(){
  return{
     visible: true,
  };
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [v-b-collapse directive](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/collapse/#usage) to toggle your collapse.

```html
<b-button v-b-collapse.collapse-1>View more</b-button>
<collapse id="collapse-1"></collapse>
```

Comment: Thanks again! but this in not working from parent. I will read more there.